# how do you programatically create sub sections in latex/sweave

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, sweave

I have a over 100 of applications and cpu and performance data for each application. I need to go through my data set and create cpu and memory charts for all these apps. Each app needs to have its own section in pdf.

Let's say, I have a application vector like this:

```
app<-c("Web", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Pod1")
```

How would I programatically create subsection for each app and insert cpu and memory?

Output could be like this:

```
1. Webb
           cpu chart
           memory chart
2. Farm1
          cpu chart
          memory chart
```

etc

I've tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{applications cpu and memory}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\tableofcontents

<<results='asis'>>=
   for (product in app){ 
    cat(paste("\\section{",product,"}", sep="")) }
    @


    \end{document}
```

I get this error when I try to compile to pdf:

```
Writing to file ddd.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
Error in match.arg(options$results, c("verbatim", "tex", "hide")) : 
  'arg' should be one of "verbatim", "tex", "hide"
Calls: <Anonymous> -> SweaveParseOptions -> check -> match.arg
Execution halted
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, just put `Sweave`'s

```
<<results=tex>>=
```

instead of (`knitr`'s)

```
<<results='asis'>>=
```

Alternatively, use `knitr`. For that you might need to call `Sweave2knitr()` on the existing files.

For reference, see [Sweave manual](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/Sweave-manual.pdf), page 13, or [`knitr` chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options).

Comment: @Hi Max, I have another question. I want to go though each app in that for loop and print out a ggplot output. I do p<-ggplot(...), then print(p) under the for loop not printing to the pdf, any ideas?